# Where did the top bar menu go?

Tags: support, design

When I look at the top bar when I'm not logged in on Stack Overflow, there is no top bar menu. I can't view the help center or the list of sites anywhere on it. All I have is this useless bar where I could view products, customers, or use cases.

[image]

If I am logged in, or if I am on a different site than Stack Overflow, the buttons are there. I'm not sure why they aren't there when we have so much free space on the bar.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the be all end all of sites on the network. I oftentimes find myself on Stack Overflow when I think that I might find more relevant questions browsing one of the dozens of other tech sites. And the reason I'm not logged in sometimes is simple: I'm at work and want to avoid the distractions of my account. I don't use the footer to navigate, ever, so that's not really a good solution.

Comment: This is a prime example of a confusing UX. The navigation buttons should be there at all times, no matter whether you're logged in.

Comment: Does _anyone_ use the footer bar to navigate? I mean the top and side bar are sticky and so they're always there when I wanna do something. I mean the bottom of the page is always _there_ too, but I have to scroll for it.

Answer (score 13):

It seems really weird to me that these links even exist in the top bar. The [left navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes) seems to be the perfect space for this use case, promoting things like the Teams *product*.

The left navigation was even [sold to us](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/02/08/information-architecture-navigating-stack-overflow-enterprise-stack-exchange-sites/) as a way to introduce scalability for future products (emphasis mine):

> Principle #2: Scalability
>
> The new information architecture also needed to scale reasonably over time. People should be able to expect a **coherent experience as the site grows and changes**. Here are some hypothetical scenarios that we can use to approximate the use cases that the information architecture needs to consider:
>
> - A new product offering that is a separate entity from Stack Overflow
> - A **new feature** on Stack Overflow

Yet, here we are, getting product offerings shoved into the face in the top bar, while sacrificing what we were promised, a *“greater experience consistency across the products”*.

I would very much welcome if the links get moved to the left navigation, considering that they promote things that aren’t really relevant to the majority of users. It would also fit with the already existing Teams advertisement that is currently displayed there for *all users*.

In addition, having this in the left navigation would mean that it would flow properly on small screens without sacrificing very valuable top bar space.