# The top bar no longer displays the moderator flag queue after the new "Products" menu

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, moderator-tools

I usually handle flags on my way back home, when I'm either walking or taking a cab. However, today, on my way back I noticed that the moderator flag queue was not present.

This is how it was shown:

> [image]

(ignore the black block, it is the list of questions from teams)

I would free-hand-red-circle the issue, but there is no moderator queue present to do so.

The moderator queue is usually not shown if the queue is empty. Therefore I assumed that the queue was empty, which is a bit surprising on a Friday evening.

However, the queue had some 100+ flags. The flag queue was not displayed because the "Products" menu takes a lot of space.

Can we get the moderator flag queue back on the top bar?

Comment: I can repro it on a Sony Xperia with firefox and chrome. I do have the chicken-friendly versions. Maybe that's why.

Comment: I had trouble repro'ing this, and found you have to scroll down to the bottom of the mobile site and tap on "Full Site" in the footer.

Comment: *I would free-hand-red-circle the issue, but there is no moderator queue present to do so.* ... excuses ..

Comment: "*I usually handle flags when I'm walking*" - eyes off your phone please, we don't want you get hit by a bus! :-)

Comment: @Bergi I was thinking the same thing, he might walk into a pole. ;)

Comment: There's a bigger question here: What secret thing were you looking at that required you to have an incognito browser window open? Actually, don't answer that... ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just pushed a change to hide the `Products` link for moderators at the smallest breakpoint *unless* you’re on a product page. Phew!

Comment: Thank you for the quickfix. Do update the status tag on the question.

Comment: There's also one more part to this - regular users can't see the help center button or review queues on small enough screens.

Comment: Yeah, both the review and help link flow “out” on small screens. Except that there is no place where they appear instead. Why is the product link getting this importance? It’s also the only link that is text on small screens which makes it waste a lot of space.. Why can’t the products link be moved to the left navigation which appears to be made for *exactly this use case*?

Comment: Why is the Products link even there? Why does it have precedence over actually important navigation? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386293/where-did-the-top-bar-menu-go

Comment: @Aaron Can we hide this `Products` link at small screens all together. It breaks a lot of the UI.