# feature-requests are being looked at!

Tags: discussion, meta, feature-request-process

Lately, there has been a lot of negativity on Meta about [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s being left hanging for months or even years without any official reply.

I noticed something very promising, the last few days, that I wanted to bring to attention:

> [image]

A lot of feature requests seem to be getting looked at, reviewed and unless declined, probably pushed through to SE's internal backlog.

This may be related to what [Tim Post♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post) said in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317221/203057):

> I think, in 2019, we're going to have to bite the bullet and replace at least bug tracking and feature requests with something else, or have something else behind the pipeline consuming meta and making sure it gets put somewhere else in ordered form so we can work from it. I don't know what that's going to look like, I just know what we've got isn't working, and breaks even more embarrassingly by the week.

---

After all our ranting about these feature requests, I feel it deserves mentioning:

## Thanks for picking up the slack, SE!

<sub><sup>(I realize this isn't really a question, but I think this shouldn't go unnoticed.)</sup></sub>

Comment: The eternal optimist in says . The eternal pessimist in says 

Comment: I've spend the last day thinking how I could write something like that after [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387132/stack-overflow-vs-stack-overflow-what-can-we-as-a-community-do-to-improve-the/387136?noredirect=1#comment712598_387136) and [this edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/385143/28) (Just to give some background)

Comment: Now they [just gotta beat me in this list](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/899223/users-whove-added-a-status-tag-to-a-post-on-meta) and my joy will know no bounds ;p

Comment: Not to be a downer and I know this is a "feel good" thread but how many of those are features which will aid in moderation? Because as I see it, that's the crux of the issue.

Comment: @Script47: It's an important aspect, yes, but at least feature requests are visibly being considered now, you downer ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus '*but at least feature requests are visibly being considered now*' - respectfully, I think that your thinking is flawed. If SO knows the community has issues with the moderation tools and that that is the biggest divider between the community and them, then surely they should immediately focus their time on improving those moderation tools rather than skirting around the other requests? Again, don't get me wrong, am I optimistic about this? Sure.

Comment: To me it looks more like they're pruning the backlog in preparation for getting a better system in place, but I'm a half-full glass kinda guy.

Comment: @Script47 Moderation tools may be the most important thing _for you_, but how can anyone know they're higher priority than other feature requests if they don't review those feature requests?

Comment: @IMSoP no, not for me only, rather the curators who've been ostracized (maybe too strong of word) for a while now. As for the priority aspect of your comment, if they intend to use this as a way to build the broken bridge with the community then surely the higher priorities would be the ones that have been voted on most by the community?

Comment: @Script47 Votes can only ever be one factor among many: it could be that there's one post where a thousand people vote for a complex proposal that would take a team of three people six to eight months to develop, and another which didn't get much attention but proposes something that will unlock a lot of potential and can be done in a couple of days. Or it might be that there are no such suggestions, and the outcome of the review is that, yes, moderation tools are the top priority - but you don't know until you've actually done the review.

Comment: @IMSoP I see what you mean but all I'm saying is this, none of the questions shown in the above picture have the tag `moderation` or `*-tools` which just makes me question what's being looked at. People have the most gripe with mod tools and surely that should be addressed. Once again, I'm glad they're doing something but that doesn't mean we shouldn't question what they're doing, I'm hesitant is all.

Comment: I, for one, am happy at least _some_ feature requests are being taken care of. It's a start.

Comment: @Script47 I'll plainly assume what I said in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387136/3627607) , that's at least a first step showing they do care about the FR on meta, consider them and this breaks the cycle of "being ignored" feeling, I for one, have had. Even if that's clearly basics things, the move toward sanitizing them, updating status, and just acting on the small ones already showcase goodwill. If we're up to reestablish a trust, the least we can do is acknowledge this move to show it goes on the right path and we're not dismissing the effort.

Comment: @Tensibai I have acknowledged it over the span of several comments I've posted and I immediately up-voted this post. Just being justifiably hesitant.

Comment: @Script47 I haven't been clear sorry, I fully understand you being hesitant, I'm still watching that unsure of how it will be in a few weeks. I just wanted to shared my feeling we have a role to play to address the "negative" perception of meta SE employees have ([free interpretation from this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089/what-does-constructive-criticism-of-a-design-change-look-like/314348#comment1030131_314348)) and that we can help breaking this perpection  :) I think we're on the same line, I'm a bit extra cautious maybe :)

Comment: on a related note I noticed promising trend in features change log at MSE. Mentioned it [in comments here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387132/stack-overflow-vs-stack-overflow-what-can-we-as-a-community-do-to-improve-the/387149#comment711634_387149) about a week ago. "keeping fingers crossed"

Comment: @Script47 Forgot a point, I think a bunch of request about moderation tools are harder to implement and won't show before weeks, so my overall point was about this acknowledgment of good faith and waiting for the more expected tools ;)

Comment: @gnat when reading this comment a few days back, I thought it was over optimistic as there's been few "tooling" updates in the log, I now share the "keeping fingers crossed" :)

Comment: @Tensibai I think regular SO users won't be much impressed by the progress in there. SE dev put solid effort into hot questions but this feature has negligible impact on SO (one can argue that option to hide HNQ is useful for SO users but that's really minor). Also, they seem to focus on moderator tools (which are I think super-important from company perspective) but this naturally has low visibility among regular users. Code fences were kind of a big prominent hit, but unfortunately after so many years of negligence it was probably perceived more like an exception, kind of accidental change

Comment: @Script47 - as a moderator on many sites, I don't think moderation tools should necessarily come first. I think each on its own merits. There are tools I'd like to see sorted, but there are also general usability improvements I'd like to see. So let's accept this is a positive step - stuff is being looked at, and hopefully the backlog will move.

Comment: This is related to the **[6 to 8 weeks Meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)** where one's ability to remember is insulted by telling the person to wait 6-8 weeks (or ignoring the request). Not CoC sanctioned behavior.

Comment: Still `Night Mode` feature is missing!

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal [the reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274390/7678788) ***Night Mode / Dark Theme*** feature is missing. But you can use [third party plugin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294045/7678788) for the same!

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal they started implementing feature requests very recently. Give it time before you claim it's missing.

Comment: @BhargavRao Challenge Accepted

Comment: @YaakovEllis good to see you here! Can you tell usif my assesment is somewhat accurate? :D

Comment: @Cerbrus I wish I could say we had a proper bug tracking system. Maybe in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Your edit on this question was flagged as low quality, and I think the flag is fair. Please try to make more substantial changes and edit summaries. (E.g. capitalizing “Enter image description here” doesn’t help, and “Active reading” doesn’t provide any information. I’m not actually sure what you mean by it.)

Comment: @Ry-: I think he has a bot / script that does these edits, automatically. That said, I don't agree with the changes it's made there.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You're welcome.

Like I said, we (the Community Dev team) are working on lot's of things here. Some initiatives were alluded to by Sara [in her blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/?cb=1). Others (which will hopefully be covered in a future blog post) will relate more to experienced users, curators and mods.

One area where we need to up our game is our process and follow-through when it comes to publicly submitted bugs and feature requests. For the time being we are still using meta for public bug submission and feature requests. My efforts highlighted above are just one instance of publicly visible efforts in this regard (there are more behind the scenes as well, by many other members of the team).

Thanks for the feedback, and I hope that we are able to continue to (re)earn your collective trust in this area.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing work. One thing that you can do is to review the questions currently tagged as [meta-tag:status-planned] and see if some of them are actually completed.

Comment: @BhargavRao I have gone through all of the `status-planned` items on the site, and cleared them out. Most were already completed or no longer relevant. One bug fixed, and a couple others sent back for further consideration.

Comment: Thanks so much for that. You seemed to have [missed one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386325). :)

Comment: @BhargavRao not anymore